# Automatic sequence diagrams

Tags: java, eclipse, sequence-diagram

I have inherited a huge codebase and I was wondering if there was any tool that allowed me to mark any method inside my project and create a sequence diagram with all the calls to classes on my package, filter them or something similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you give [Architexa](http://www.architexa.com/) a try. Eclipse plugin and free for personal use.

Comment: It works fine, but generation a sequence diagram for the stacktrace is bugged ATM :(

Comment: Found a bug? Nice !! Could you please raise it with them http://www.architexa.com/support/index  These guys are unbelievably friendly. And we get to have a great product for free.

Comment: And NO. I don't get a commission from them. LOL

Comment: One hour after registration they sent me an (automated) email asking me how my experience was. So far I've returned two emails with feedback on functionality and bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [trace to sequence diagram generation python scripts](https://github.com/eventhelix/trace-to-sequence-diagram). You can customize these scripts to generate sequence diagrams using [EventStudio System Designer](http://www.eventhelix.com/EventStudio/).

Note the EventStudio is not a free tool. I am affiliated with the company.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented  a  junit test based  sequence generator which generates sequence diagrams for the  pgf-umlsd latex package example:
[image: Generated sequence diagram]

Hello world

```
@Test
@SequenceDiagram({ Controller.class, Model.class })
public void testMethod() {
    Controller c = new Controller(new Model());
    c.init();
    c.simpleBeanOperation();
}
```

https://github.com/sherif181/java-sequence-diagram-generator

Comment: Hey sherif, mind linking to your published diagram generator?